# 123456000-й словами

Tags: грамматика, орфография, числительные

Порядковые числительные, оканчивающийся на `-сотый`, `-тысячный`, `-милионный` и т.д., пишутся [слитно](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_110)[2](http://saassl.at.tut.by/Book/index66.htm):

> 1. Составные числительные пишутся раздельно, имея столько слов, сколько в числе значащих цифр, не считая нулей (ПЯТЬСОТ ДВАДЦАТЬ ТРИ. ПЯТЬСОТ ДВАДЦАТЬ ТРЕТИЙ). Однако порядковые числительные, оканчивающиеся на -ТЫСЯЧНЫЙ, -МИЛЛИОННЫЙ, -МИЛЛИАРДНЫЙ пишутся слитно (СТОТЫСЯЧНЫЙ, ДВУХСОТТРИДЦАТИПЯТИМИЛЛИАРДНЫЙ).

Возникает резонный вопрос: до какой части пишется все слитно?

- "сто двадцать три миллиона четырёхсотпятидесятишеститысячный"

или

- "стодвадцатитрёхмиллионогочетырёхсотпятидесятишеститысячный"?

или другие варианты?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, и, если предположить, что вы написали в заголовке именно то, что имели в виду, ваше числительное, вынесенное в заголовок, является неправильным, даже будучи количественным, или вы просто неверно его записали: нет таких числительных, как '*сто двадцать три тысячи четыреста пятьдесят шесть тысяч'. Это звучит как пресловутое 'стопятьсот'.

Если же вы имеете в виду число 123 456 000 (сто двадцать три миллиона четыреста пятьдесят шесть тысяч), то порядковое числительное от него образуется легко, [по обычным правилам](http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.30):

> сто двадцать три миллиона четырёхсотпятидесятишеститысячный

Всё слитно пишется до того разряда, к которому относятся последние тройки нулей, в данном случае это тысячи, поэтому количество тысяч (456) пишется слитно, а всё, что больше - раздельно. Если бы мы имели дело с числом 123 456 000 000, то тут уже количество миллионов будет писаться слитно, а миллиардов - раздельно:

> сто двадцать три миллиарда четырёхсотпятидесятишестимиллионный

И, соответственно, в числе 123 456 789 000 опять таки слитно будет писаться количество тысяч (789), поскольку тут всего одна тройка нулей, тысячи:

> сто двадцать три миллиарда четыреста пятьдесят шесть миллионов семисотвосьмидесятидевятитысячный

Comment: Первый абзац я вообще не понял о чем вы. Имел ввиду я "123456000-й". Почему вы считаете, что окончание "-тысячный" вместо "000-й" неправильным?

Comment: Но все-равно, это именно то, что я хотел узнать.

Comment: @hazzik - Конечно же так нельзя писать, как у вас. "-тысячный" обозначает количество тысяч, напр. "10-тысячный", поэтому если прочитать ваше число, то и будет так, как я написал в первом абзаце. Короче, вы написали так, как если бы я хотел написать "102-й", а написал бы "10-второй".

Comment: Во-первых, пример, который вы привели - 102-й, он никакого отношения не имеет к "-тысячный". Во-вторых, я не вижу никаких правил, говорящих, что нельзя сокращать кратные 1000  (в степени N) числительные, которые выходят за порядок сокращения (миллионы при круглых тысячах, миллиарды при миллионах и  т.д.). Почему можно писать 100-тысячный, но не 1100-тысячный? 
Покажите мне правило.

Comment: @hazzik - А вы можете написать "1100-тысячный" словами? "Тысячастотысячный" что ли? Вот именно об этом я и написал в первом абзаце.

Comment: "1100-тысячный" словами будет "один миллион стотысячный", а не "Тысячастотысячный", что вы как маленький?

Comment: @hazzik - А «1000000-тысячный» по-вашему читается «миллиардный»?